# Adding Image Texture to .STL/.OBJ/.PLY Model in Blender

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I have a model which has been meshed from pointcloud data and imported into blender as a modea(.stl normally, but can be OBJ OR PLY).

I have some textures (as jpegs) imported from quixel bridge. However when I try to apply the image texture, only a solid color appears on the model (brown or black). I have checked nodes correctly and also displays the same in render view.

The image texture applies perfectly to the default cube, but not to my imported model.

Any advice would be apppreciated.

Comment: Point clouds as in no faces? You'll need faces for regular UVs to work.

Comment: The user stated the point cloud was meshed (thus the use of STL), my guess is he did not unwrap.